# C# .net Make checkboxes to behave as a radio button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a group box which has some radio buttons. I am trying to implement serialization with the help of a tutorial from Code Project. That tutorial supports serialization of checkboxes and not radio buttons. So i need to make the radio buttons in my app as checkboxes (that is they should be check boxes but work like a radiobutton).

I tried writing code, but what happens is when I find that a particular checkbox is checked and I go to uncheck or vice versa, it triggers that checked_changed event handler and this goes into an infinite loop.

Can someone help me out with this?

Thanks

UPDATE:

After seeing your replies, I would like to say thanks a lot. Yes, You are all right that we should not be messing with the basic properties. I will work with changing the serialization method.

P.S The link for the tutorial is http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/SavingTheStateOfAForm.aspx

Final Update:

After following the replies posted here, I decided not to change the default properties but to change the serializer code. I did that and it now works perfectly. Thanks a lot, everyone.

Comment: Ack... don't do this. Controls are standardised for a reason - If a user sees radiobutons they expect only 1 can be selected. If they see checkboxes they expect to be able to multi-select.

Comment: 1) Post some code.  2) How about a link to the tutorial. 3) Making CheckBoxes perform like RadioButtons sounds like a bad idea.  I think a better idea would be to change the serialization to support RadioButtons.

Comment: Why not simply implement serialization of radio buttons the same way as the serialization of checkboxes? Should not make big difference.

Comment: I agree with @Jamiec.  If the tutorial doesn't have radio buttons, either find a different tutorial or we can try to help you implement it correctly.  Either way, fix the implementation.  Don't try to change the underlying controls.

Comment: This is why we have radio button. The check box class this event and somehow disabling this and doing all you saying is like making a user control which is radio button (just looks square rather than round) . I would just use radio button rather than writing a new control.

Comment: Yes, I can help you out: ***FORGET ALL ABOUT IT***. It is WRONG and NOT NICE to change the behavior of checkboxes. It confuses everybody. And besides, it's stupid and a waste of time. Don't do that, please. Just don't do it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with all the commenters: **do not make checkboxes that act like radio buttons**, it flies in the face of UI conventions and confuses users.

The right way to do this is to fix your code to serialize the radio buttons, but without seeing your code it's hard to know how to help you. For a start, you can fix the `CheckedChanged` looping by temporarily removing the event handler before you do anything. For example:

```
myCheckBox.CheckedChanged -= MyCheckedChangedEventHandler;
myCheckBox.Checked = true;
myCheckBox.CheckedChanged += MyCheckedChangedEventHandler;
```

If this alone doesn't fix your issue, please show us your code and we'll try to help more.

**Edit:** Based on the tutorial listed in your update, I'm guessing the problem happens when you call `FormSerialisor.Deserialise()`, which triggers your controls' event handlers to fire? If that's the case, the quick fix is to just do what I mentioned: remove the radio button event handlers before calling `FormSerialisor.Deserialise()` and then re-add them afterwards. Example:

```
myRadioButton.CheckedChanged -= MyCheckedChangedEventHandler;
FormSerialisor.Deserialise(this, mySerialisepath);
myRadioButton.CheckedChanged += MyCheckedChangedEventHandler;
```

You may also need to edit the FormSerialisor class to handle RadioButtons; just copy the code that handles checkboxes but change all the references to RadioButton. It's not clear from your question whether this step will be necessary or not.

Comment: I understood what you are trying to tell. The tutorial does not handle radio buttons. I will change it to handle them as well. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your post. I did not use the register/unregister checked event. All I did was edited the serializer class to handle radio buttons. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments say, you're better of getting serialisation to work with radio buttons than messing around with checkboxes.  Having said that, to get the effect you need, just set a variable that indicates you're already handling a change event, and test for it.  Something like this (it's terrible code, but demonstrates the idea):

```
    private bool autoChange = false;
    private void ChangeHandler() {
        if (!autoChange) {
            autoChange = true;
            /* Do stuff */
            autoChange = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unregister from the `Checked`event (by using `-=`) before doing that. And re-register after you're done.

(I'm not arguing with the comments. Just answering the question.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hello, here a simple ansewer to transform the CheckBox to a RadioButton:**

```
object clickBox = null;

 private void checkBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clickBox = sender;

        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is CheckBox)
            {
                if (c != clickBox)
                {
                    ((CheckBox)c).Checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

**And add this Click event o every Checkbox**
Finish

Answer (score 0):

Take the **CheckedListBox** and call ***ItemCheck*** Event and use below code It will behave like Radio buttons (It works for me):-

```
 private void chkListBox_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            for (int item = 0; item < chkListBox.Items.Count; item++)
            {
                chkListBox.SetItemChecked(item, false);
            }
        }
    }
```